# I want to perform data analysis using python

Tags: python, data-analysis, analysis

I just want to do these 3 steps:

1. identify the missing data
2. impute the missing values in the data using k-means or k-nearest-neighbor imputation.
3. return the imputed data and compare it with the complete data to measure the accuracy and reliability of your results

Kindly suggest how to do it.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a coding service. Please read the following documentation, then [edit] and rephrase the question. [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) & [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Always [Provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example (e.g. code, data, errors) as text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) & you're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't formulated very well, but here's some things that might work for your application.

1. pandas.isnan
2. pandas.interpolate
3. mse = lambda y1, y2: (y2 - y1)**2

Answer (score 0):

so you have data set in csv format or other. you can first load the data using the pandas library and fill the missing values.

Build the model :
mse = lambda y1, y2: (y2 - y1)**2

Test with sample data set on this model.